# Produce jar with libs for use on Android / Desktop

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

I'm trying to produce a standard JAR file that can be used on both desktop Java, and also Android, by 3rd parties and distributed manually.  The JAR itself uses nothing that doesnt work on Android.

The jar needs to depend on some other 3rd party libs and I'd like to bundle them into it, to avoid the user having to add their own dependencies on these.

I can't seem to get this working, running on Android just gives ClassNotFound for the libs.  I have tried something like

```
jar {
    into('libs') {
        from configurations.compile
}

manifest {
    attributes(
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { "libs/"+it.getName() }.join(' '))
}
}
```

Which produces a jar, with the required jars in libs but it still doesnt work.  Is this even supported, or do I need to produce both a jar for desktop and an aar specifically for Android?

Many thanks

Comment: "I'd like to bundle them into it" -- this is generally frowned upon in modern app development.

Comment: You could produce a so called fat jar however you should really avoid that. What is the problem with a normal lib on a maven repo. You can define in the pom file their dependencies so if you link to your lib your dependencies will be added automatically.

Comment: "this is generally frowned upon in modern app development" - yep, thankfully.  Its a very specific 3rd party lib which I'm 100% sure wont be used by the target application.  The lib is in the healthcare space and contains company IP and can only be distributed to our clients.  Its obfuscated & encrypted using 3rd party tools.